# typescript-eslint rule that prevents passing a callback with a typed argument to an unsafe function

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to be super strict in my typescript codebase with regards to `any`. I'm using all the `no-unsafe-*` rules, so my `.eslintrc.js` includes:

```
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument': 'error',
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment': 'error',
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call': 'error',
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access': 'error',
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return': 'error',
```

and yet I've just been bitten by an `any`-caused bug.

Let's suppose an external library has this code:

```js
type Callback = (x: any) => void;

function invokesCallback(callback: Callback): void {
  callback({ thisWill: 'break everything' });
}
```

and then, in my codebase, I have this:

```js
function appendNumber(value: number) {
  someNumbers.push(value);
}

const someNumbers: number[] = [];
invokesCallback(appendNumber);
```

I don't see any (pun unintended) static check errors here, and I'd certainly like to!

So, to sum up, I'd like to know if there's a rule which, knowing that the type of a callback is something like `(x: any) => void;`, **only** allows functions with this signature to be pass as the callback: `(x: unknown) => void;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the most direct answer is the best. [`plugin:@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any) bans explicit uses of the `any` type.

If you don't have control of that `any` then alas, no, there is no lint rule like this in typescript-eslint. <s>You might want to [file an issue on typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/issues/new/choose) suggesting one.</s>

Edit: [@LGenzelis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1224602/lgenzelis) did file an issue on typescript-eslint! [Rule proposal: no-unsafe-callback](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4300). It was marked as accepting PRs (meaning: anybody can send a pull request to implement it) in December 2021, and as of January 2024 is still awaiting a PR.

Comment: Indeed, here I'm talking about an external library. I opened an issue, shortly after posting this question :) If you'd like that too, an upvote can never hurt! https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4300

Comment: Aha! Great - glad to see it's accepting PRs. Edited in the post. Thanks! You have my . 